SimpleInjector. How to resolve instances which has parameters that could be evaluated only in runtime
I have a lot of objects in my program that are created at runtime with at least 1 parameter. There are many nested classes where a new data is evaluated, which is necessary for next inner instances.
At first, let me briefly describe the structure, and then I'll provide you with the simplified example.
Structure description.

An user sends string request ->
Program determines IRequestContext and ICommand ->
ICommand.Execute(IRequestContext) is called ->
The execution creates IStep[] and IPlan(IStep[]) via factory and sends it to scheduler ->
At a certain time scheduler launches IPlan with the IRequestContext.
IPlan executes step by step by calling IObservable<Report> IStep.Make(IRequestContext) ->
An implementations of IStep contains buffer instances to share result of their execution in scope of current plan. It's not returned but it's necessary to produce final Report, but not only for this purpose. Buffer can't have interface cause it's a storage of data after all.
Report contains enum Result and IMessageBuilder. IMesageBuilder has only 1 method Build().

Details
Each class has a lot of dependencies by itself such as interfaces for work with database, localization, communication API. This dependencies are registred at the composition root. They are not problem in this case.
An instance of IRequestContext is created at the runtime for each user request. IStep, IMessageBuilder and all sorts of buffers depend on it. Therefore I can't just register SomeMessageBuilder, because the necessary data for a builder is being created during the step execution. And different requests can't share the same instance of message builder or buffer.
For each implementation of IMessageBuilder there will be different count and types of parameters. That is why I can't change interface to accept this entities like IMessageBuilder.Build(Entity1, Entity2, ...). Therefore I have to create and register factories for each implementation of IMessageBuilder. As a result each IStep implementation has dependency from a IFactory<T1,T2,...,IMessageBuilder>.
Each IPlan implementation has it's own factory which creates unique combination of steps. Furthermore I use implementation of composite pattern for steps such as CompositeStep(IStep[] step) : IStep. Therefore I have to register factory for each implementation of IStep, and I have to register factory for each CompositeStep which consists of different steps.
Simplified example
Please keep in mind that I have dozen of different IPlan implementations which can use same steps.
Some interfaces and class for clarification.
public interface IPlan<in TContext,out TReport>{
  IObservable<TReport> Execute(TContext context);
  bool IsReadyToGoNext(TReport report);
}
public interface IStep<in TContext,out TReport>{
  IObservable<TReport> Make(TContext context);
}
public interface IFactory<in T1, out TObject>
{
  TObject Create(T1 param);
}

public interface IMessageBuilder{
  SendMessage Build();
}
public class CreateMessageBuilder : LocalizedMessageBuilder, IMessageBuilder
{
  public CreateMessageBuilder(long chatId, CultureInfo info
  , ILocalizationProvider localizationProvider, int minSymbols, int maxSymbols)
  {...}
  public  void SetUser(UserRepresentation representation){...};
  public void SetSirena(SirenRepresentation sirena){...};
  public void IsUserAllowedToCreateSirena(bool isAllowed){...};
  public void IsTitleValid(bool isValid){...};
  public override SendMessage Build(){...};
}

Example of plan factory:
public class CreateSirenaPlanFactory : IFactory<IRequestContext,CommandPlan>
{
  private readonly Container container;
  private readonly IFactory<IRequestContext, CreateMessageBuilder> messageBuilderFactory;
  private readonly IFactory<CreateMessageBuilder, CreateSirenaStep.Buffer> bufferFactory;

  public CreateSirenaPlanFactory(Container container
  , IFactory<IRequestContext, CreateMessageBuilder> messageBuilderFactory
  , IFactory<CreateMessageBuilder,CreateSirenaStep.Buffer>  bufferFactory)
  
  {
    this.container = container;
    this.messageBuilderFactory = messageBuilderFactory;
    this.bufferFactory = bufferFactory;
  }

  public IPlan Create(IRequestContext context)
  {
    CreateMessageBuilder messageBuilder = messageBuilderFactory.Create(context);
    CreateSirenaStep.Buffer buffer = bufferFactory.Create(messageBuilder);

//Same buffer instance has to be shared between group of steps below
//But for each new request a new instance of plan and of buffer has to be created
    var validation = new CompositeCommandStep([
      container.GetInstance<CheckAbilityToCreateSirenaStep>(),
      container.GetInstance<ValidateTitleCreateSirenaStep>()
    ]);
    
    IStep<IRequestContext,CommandStep.Report>[] steps = [
      container.GetInstance<GetUserCreateSirenaStep>(),
      validation,
      container.GetInstance<RequestDBToCreateSirenaStep>(),
    ];
    return new CommandPlan(CreateSirenaCommand.NAME,steps);
  }
}

Question
How to bind this? I'm not eager to create factory for each IStep implementation that depends on 1 and more parameters, that being produced during a runtime. And I don't know how to bind the buffer in this situation at all since SimpleInjector doesn't have context.
P.S.
When I worked with Unity engine and with Zenject/Extenject there were much more options to divide contexts of a bindings and to create conditional bindings for an instances from certain factory. It's a pity that SimpleInjector has a lack of such tools.
Because for each plan instance I could create context. And there would be 1 buffer instance created for each context. Furthermore I don't need to create factory for each instance which need paramteres, because I could just bind native factory with parameters. It was a huge wonder for me when I found out that documentation doesn't provide information about context, only about scopes. But I can't create buffer instance in scope, because the scope will be closed just when Create method will finish it work, and the instance would be disposed as I understood from the documentation. Perhaps I can use Flowing scope, however I still don't understand what is the way to resolve instance with parameter(s).

Have you seen the docs for context based injection?

Simple Injector does not have any built-in features that allow initializing components with runtime data. That's by design. Please read this.

@qujck  Yes. I read most of documentation on the site. Context-based is useful but when you have dozen implementations with the same interface It makes code really hard to maintain. I had that problem on my previous project with Zenject until I found out how to use subcontainers and context. But it's not the solvation of problem in my case, because I have runtime parameters. And I can't register them

Thank you Steven for the article. I totally agree with the issues raised in this article. And I agree that it would be better to restructure my code. But unfortunately the article provides too simplified solutions that are not connected with the real world problem or I just can't figure out how to apply those solutions to my code.
If you don't mind I would like to discuss what I see as a flaws of those solutions in relation towards my case. I can update my question with my concerns. But it's hard to make dialogue in SO. Or I may create topic on SI github page. Which way is better?

In your case, A discussion on Github would likely be more suited.
